# xdt:Transform not working on URI section in web.config

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2012, uri, web.config-transform

I am looking at configuring my asp.net project to support multiple configurations (Debug, Release). I've been able to successfully modify the Web.Debug.config file to properly transform different elements in the regular web.config file. IE, I added the following section and it works correctly:

```
  <location path="images" xdt:Transform="Insert">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
```

However, I am having issues transforming the URI element. When I add this:

```
  <uri xdt:Transform="Insert">
    <idn enabled="All" />
    <iriParsing enabled="true" />
  </uri>
```

I get the following warning message: "**The 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform:Transform' attribute is not declared.**"

When I try to auto complete the URI section, the xdt:Transform tag and other xdt tags don't show up (while in every other section in the file it does). The URI section is nested within the configuration section

```
<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
```

Does anyone have any idea on what might be going on and how to fix it?

Thanks.